# In Catacombs, how do the remaining party members deal with a dead Hero's possession?

Tags: catacombs

The rules (3rd edition) say that

> Only the hero who owns the item may use it and items cannot be given away or traded.

and that

> Players may, but are not obligated to, pool their gold

The Resurrect Hero Service description also seems to imply that a dead player keeps his/her possessions

> The hero returns to life with all of his or her gold coins and unused Item and/or Spell cards.

Is it still possible in this case to add the dead hero's gold in the pool (for instance to pay for his/her resurrection)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

The [game rules](https://elzra.com/catacombs/downloads.html?download=11:catacombs-third-edition-manual-v21), pg 11 (12 of the pdf) say:

> At this point, that hero is out of the game unless the remaining heroes reach Althea the Healer and resurrect the dead hero (see page 16). Due to this possibility, the dead hero retains control of any spells, gold coins and or items that he or she has collected. **Dead heroes may not use their gold coins or offer them to other players in any special room until successfully resurrected.**